# SBT Publish Fails - Sonatype Nexus .3.2.1-01 OSS

Tags: nexus

After upgrade from 2.14.3 to 3.2.1-01 in nexus OSS, sbt universal:publish started failing. It fails with error java.io.IOException: Error writing to server.

Nexus log does not give any information. This is a blocker for us. Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Full error trace is below.

java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:699)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:711)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1567)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:91)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1466)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1464)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1463)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.upload(BasicURLHandler.java:264)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:150)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLRepository.put(URLRepository.java:84)
    at sbt.ConvertResolver$LocalIfFileRepo.put(ConvertResolver.scala:243)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository.put(AbstractRepository.java:130)
    at sbt.ConvertResolver$ChecksumFriendlyURLResolver$class.put(ConvertResolver.scala:81)
    at sbt.ConvertResolver$$anonfun$defaultConvert$1$PluginCapableResolver$1.put(ConvertResolver.scala:115)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.publish(RepositoryResolver.java:216)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$3.apply(IvyActions.scala:336)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$3.apply(IvyActions.scala:335)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.publish(IvyActions.scala:335)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.withChecksums(IvyActions.scala:130)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$withChecksums(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:114)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:127)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:124)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.publish(IvyActions.scala:114)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$publishTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1283)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$publishTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1282)
    at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:35)
    at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (universal:publish) java.io.IOException: Error writing to server

Comment: Can you share any of your sbt publish config (genericized is fine as long as I can see URLs/Realm etc...)?

Comment: val nexus = http://<>:8081/nexus/

credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials")
publishTo in ThisBuild := {
  if (isSnapshot.value) Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
    else Some("releases" at nexus + "content/repositories/releases")
}  note that with same configuration sbt publish works w/o any issues. It fails only for sbt universal:publish.

Comment: A few things to check out, those urls for snapshots/releases will still work, but there are newer ones you can use for Nexus Repository 3 which are something like /repository/{repository-name}/.

Comment: If Universal Publish isn't working, I'm curious what you are deploying in total to Nexus Repository? Are you generating RPMs or anything like that?

Comment: right now just deploying jar libraries using sbt publish.

Comment: @JayeshGohil : hi, i've just find your ask.....and we have the same problem. Can you say us how you solved it ? we tried to universal:publish a zip file and it doesn't work...

Comment: @flagadajones Hi, unfortunately I never got it to solve. Although this was not the reason but we have migrated to Artifactory.